# Python error - redirect trying to parse webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.animeplus.tv/anime-show-list/")
content =(html.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(soup.prettify())
```

The script works fine with other webpages, but I run the program for my targeted website I get.

```
<meta .$_server["request_uri"]."'"="" content="0;URL='" http-equiv="refresh"/>
```

I do not really understand the html code.

I assume it's some sort of redirect or way to prevent web scraping.

Is there a way for python to access the code after the redirect or in a way the browser would return the source code?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the source page borked their PHP code

Comment: Getting the page via curl also returns the same response -- I tried following redirects/changing the user agents, but no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that the page redirects to itself and sets the `Cookie` header which is important, without it you would not get the HTML you see in the browser.

Here's the solution using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) - opening up the same page in the same `session`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.animeplus.tv/anime-show-list/"
session = requests.session()
session.get(url)
response = session.get(url)  # open up the page second time
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
print(soup.title.text)  # prints: "Watch Anime | Anime Online | Free Anime | English Anime | Watch Anime Online - AnimePlus.tv"
```

Alternatively, you can use [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), but it doesn't support python 3 at the moment. Here's how it works:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> browser = mechanize.Browser()
>>> browser.open('http://www.animeplus.tv/anime-show-list/')
>>> print browser.response().read()
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Watch Anime | Anime Online | Free Anime | English Anime | Watch Anime Online - AnimePlus.tv</title> 
...
```